# Uploading TableView after calling CellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: swift, parsing, tableview, for-in-loop

this definitely isnt the best way to do this, so if you have a better answer please I am open to suggestions... i am a new programmer. I have an instagram type profile displaying 3 buttons per cell... imageView1, imageView2, and imageView3. They are buttons because when a user clicks on them I want to go to another VC to display the image. So, my problem is that I want to populate the buttons with images from picPostArray. I run a for in loop in CellForRowAtIndexPath. I think it works however I am not sure how to refresh the tableview to display the new data. My other profile data is all refreshed after ViewDidAppear and it works fine. Thanks :)

```
                 CellForRowAtIndexPath:
                 for i in 0..<picPostArray.count/3 {

                        cell.imageView1.imageView!.image = picPostArray[(i * 3) + 0]

                        cell.imageView2.imageView!.image = picPostArray[(i * 3) + 1]

                       cell.imageView3.imageView!.image = picPostArray[(i * 3) + 2]



        }

                    return cell

                }
      return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload your data you have to use `tableView.relaodData()`.

Btw, If you're going to have always 3 images in your array then you can do something like this:

```
if picPostArray.count == 3 {
      cell.imageView1.imageView!.image = picPostArray[0]
      cell.imageView2.imageView!.image = picPostArray[1]
      cell.imageView3.imageView!.image = picPostArray[2]
    }
```

Otherwise, if your array its going to be dynamic but multiple of 3.

```
let row = indexPath.row 
 cell.imageView1.imageView!.image = picPostArray[row * 3 + 0]
 cell.imageView2.imageView!.image = picPostArray[row * 3 + 1]
 cell.imageView3.imageView!.image = picPostArray[row * 3 + 2]
```